# How to store array of aliases in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

What is the best way to add aliases to a user when a user can have many aliases? Aliases will be queried heavily as an alternative to a User ID.

Imagine I have a `Users` table:

```
Users
- id
```

I can, of course, create another table, `Aliases`:

```
Aliases
- id
- user_id
- name
```

But what about using a Postgres array inside of `Users`:

```
Users
- id
- aliases (array)
```

Which is more performant?

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil. Favor the method which is easiest to read/debug/maintain.

Comment: I agree 100%. Frankly, I'm looking for an excuse to use the Postgres array, but I'm not sure if it's right for what I'm thinking about using it for (aliases).

Comment: I think the default practice would be to normalize aliases into a separate table. However, if you know you are looking for an excuse to use an interesting technology, call it "education" and just do it.

Comment: Arrays are more compact than the sum of equivalent rows, but any insert/update/delete values in them means rewriting the entire array each time, which is much less efficient than rows.

Comment: @DanielVérité Additionally, GIN or GiST indexes on array columns are less efficient to query, take up more space, and are *much* more expensive to update than a b-tree on a normalized side-table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normalize to a side-table. There's no real reason to do anything else here.

If you use arrays then you'll probably land up rewriting the array whenever any other field of the user tuple changes. I say "probably" because longer arrays could get pushed out-of-line for compressed storage in a `TOAST` table, in which case they can be updated by reference, but you lose the benefits of data locality.

Updating GiST or (especially) GIN indexes, like those required if you want to do array member-of queries, is much more expensive than updating a b-tree. Querying them is generally less efficient too. That's the price of their flexibility.

If you store out-of-line in a side table you'll pay quite a large (around 28 bytes) per-row overhead, but your indexes are likely to be smaller and faster. You'll have fewer locking issues. The optimizer can make smarter choices with simple joins than with GIN or GiST queries and will have better statistics to base those choices on. You can apply uniqueness constraints properly. Your client tools will understand the value without needing special help with array handling. It's almost certainly the way to go.

Arrays do have their place, but should generally be something you investigate *after* you've done it the basic way, if and when you find that you need to denormalize and find evidence that arrays can help you with a particular problem.